# htaccess - rewrite directories to files to be more clean

Tags: .htaccess

Currently, mysite.com/profile is rewritten to mysite.com/profile.php. I also want to pass arguments in the clean format, like mysite.com/profile/43/settings to mysite.com/profile.php?1=43&2=settings and mysite.com/thread/223/reply would be written to mysite.com/thread.php?1=223&2=reply.

Answer (score 0):

Typically, in order to enable clean parameters like that, you wouldn't actually use a different rewrite rule.  You would use your same exact front controller rewrite rule to direct everything to `profile.php`.  Then within the script you would break apart the URI into it's specific components (and provide appropriate headers of the URI didn't match a specific resource for example).

The reason for this is that the rewrite rule does not do a very good job of handling arbitrary numbers of parameters.  If you know you will always have two parameters for example, then it is easy enough to use a rewrite rule as it is easy to do something like:

```
RewriteRule /?profile/(.*)/(.*) /profile.php?param1=$1&param2=$2
```

But when you don't know how many parameters you are going to get, it becomes way more complex build rewrite rules to handle such cases.

You are best advised to work with a PHP router class (Google it, you should find plenty of options or guidance) to inspect the URI and take the appropriate actions.